# Jquery multiple files upload with usingCode igniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

In this [**link**](http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_18/Integrate_Uploadify_multiple_file_upload__with_CodeIgniter) there is js file **"vortexdev.js"** , In this JS file there is a uploadify function in that

```
 ''script'    : base_url + 'index.php?/controller/uploadifyuploader','
```

I do not know whether this function is getting called. When I select multiple files to upload, I can only see `swf` images but nothing is getting uploaded.

How do I `debug` this atleast ?

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var base_url = $('#hiddenBaseUrl').val();
  var uploadfolder = $('#uploadfolder').val();  
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : base_url + 'flash/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : base_url + 'index.php/uploadify/uploadifyUploader/',
    'cancelImg' : base_url + 'css/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : uploadfolder,
    'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.zip;*.rar;*.flv;*.mp4;*.mp3',
    'auto'      : false,
    'multi'     : true,

     'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

         // here i'm gonna resize the images and display it in the main page 

    }
  });
```

Comment: please paste full js code to undetstand the problem

Comment: @Desert P: Updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is yii page but could help you to solve this problem

[click to uplodify details](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/uploadify/)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer to my question.In your link too, I see a js fn, in that there is script which is calling the controller.NOw,I had done litte debugging, I did not use ajax but directly I posted to controller so my controller is working. only thing is my js has 'script' :controller, this is not getting called.

Comment: app i did not use this plugin i used swfupload which work same you can view about that from this link  http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/swfupload/

Comment: Can you tell me, why my controller is not getting called ? I have spent lot of time so I have to fix this, seeing a new one will again take some time.

Comment: i think you should use move_uploaded_file() function on controller